# Pagination on front page

Tags: drupal-7, pagination, content-management-system, drupal-theming

I am currently developing a drupal theme for a client.
I had a Drupal training, but we hadn't time to see pagination system, neither how to customize it (markup).

I had a look at theme_pager(). But I can't put it up on my home page (page--front.tpl.php).

I don't use the Views module because I succeeded to do without this module for the entire site.

Do you have a solution ? a tutorial about that ?

thank you,

Comment: You need to give more details about how you are displaying your data. The only thing I see is that you're not using Views but that doesn't tell us much.

Answer (score 0):

`theme_pager` function is used to dynamically generate the markup for every pager on your website.

There are around five functions, used by Drupal only for this task, but you can customize pretty-much anything just by overriding the default `theme_pager` in your theme.

What you need is to grab the initial source code from [Drupal.org](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21pager.inc/function/theme_pager/7)

Replace the `theme` with your theme name eg. `foo_pager` and put that code in to your `foo/template.php`

You will **have** to understand the algorithm behind it to adjust it properly.